# List not updating if data structure updates

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having a list of elements that i am showing in a fragment. I am loading the list OnCreateView. But somehow the list is not updated if I add new items. Do I need to refresh it somehow?

```
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false)

        val myRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)

        // Set the adapter
        // TODO: fix this
        if (myRecyclerView is RecyclerView) {
            with(myRecyclerView) {
                layoutManager = when {
                    columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
                }
                adapter = MyTripDataRecyclerViewAdapter(CountingList.countings)
            }
        }

        return view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you invalidate the adapter after you added the items to the adapter? You didn't provide enough information.

What is invalidate:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()

How to use it is like:

```
adapter.setItems(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: the delete function is in the MainActivity. How do i get the adapter from the fragment

val myRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)

does not work